# Create war file and deploy in tomcat using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, tomcat, maven-3

I have maven project which on build creates a war file. Once war is deployed, the REST url is exposed.
Is it possible to create war file within Dockerfile?`xxx.war`
This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0
 
ADD "./xxx.war" /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/xxx.war
 
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
 
EXPOSE 8080
```

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multi stage `dockerfile`, like this:

`FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as BUILD
COPY src /usr/src/myapp/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/myapp
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/myapp/pom.xml clean package`

`FROM tomcat:7.0
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/myapp/target/xxx.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/xxx.war
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: is it possible to use git for source or jenkinsfile?

Comment: Its possible, but if you authenticate via jenkins credential then according to me its not, if you want whole jenkins in container then you can have jenkins file and git and credentials in dockerfile(In this case you will need to attach volume for jenkins workspace and config_dir).

Over all, if you have dedicated jenkins server then, dont use git inside the container.